# Can TypeScript change the return type of a function by the type of the parameter?

Tags: typescript

I have a function whose return type is dependent in its input.
The input can be either defined or undefined.
If it is undefined, it returns early with a string.
If it is defined, it only return with a string if certain conditions are met. Otherwise it returns undefined.

The return in the `example` function gives the following error:

```
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'X extends number ? string | undefined : string'
```

Code:

```
function example<X extends number | undefined>(n: X): X extends number ? string | undefined : string {
  if (typeof n === "undefined") {
    return "Number is not defined";
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    return "No negative number allowed";
  }
  if (n > 100) {
    return "Number is too big";
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

I added the conditional return type as seen in the example above.
I expected the linter allow the `return undefined;` at the end of the example function.

Edit 2023-11-11:

I have also tries function overloading with the following code, but this gives me a different error:

```
This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.
```

```
function example(n: undefined): string;
function example(n: number): string | undefined {
  if (typeof n === "undefined") {
    return "Number is not defined";
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    return "No negative number allowed";
  }
  if (n > 100) {
    return "Number is too big";
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Comment: This looks like two different issues; you might want to [edit] to ask about just one of those.  For the first: TS cannot narrow generic type parameters via control flow, which is the subject of [ms/TS#33912](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).  For the second: TS does not do "distributive/multivariate control flow analysis" as explained in [ms/TS#54252](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54252#issuecomment-1548216814). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining (but it would be nice to focus on *one* of those). If not what am I missing?

Comment: Just adding to this you'll probably need to use function overloading instead for this unfortunately due to those limitations. Its a common bugbear because it looks like this should work on first glance, and it would otherwise be ergonomic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function example<
  X extends number | undefined,
  Y = X extends undefined ? string : string | undefined
>(n: X): Y {
  if (typeof n === "undefined") {
    return "Number is not defined" as Y;
  }
  if (n < 0) {
    return "No negative number allowed" as Y;
  }
  if (n > 100) {
    return "Number is too big" as Y;
  }
  return undefined as Y;
}


const a = example(2113)       // string | undefined
const b = example(undefined)  // string
```

Of course the `as Y` forced casting looks hacky, but by default VSC/TSC cannot recognize the type.

This error appears without forced casting:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Y'.
  'Y' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.ts(2322)
```

The `Y` generic type is introduced, to be able to do easy type casts inside the code.

Personally i'd create a function what checks if the number is undefined like:

```
function isUndefined(value: unknown): value is undefined {
 return typeof value === "undefined";
}
```

And then build more functions on top of that, to separate the different flows instead of doing everything inside a single function. To do not have a big-hairy object.

My overall opinion is typescript can be forced to do this in a single function, but separate the different decisions to their respective function would generate much cleaner and scalable code.